# Combinatorial proof of $\binom{n+2}{3} = 1 \cdot n + 2 \cdot (n-1) + 3 \cdot (n-2) + \cdots + n \cdot 1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

A combinatorial proof of the following relation:
$$\binom{n+2}{3} = 1 \cdot n + 2 \cdot (n-1) + 3 \cdot (n-2) + \cdots + n \cdot 1$$

---

So one side is the number of ways to choose $3$ numbers from $n+2$ numbers and the other side I did like this:

[image]

Comment: Your combinatorial proof seems fine.

Comment: Clever! I'd state it as something like: first choose the middle-largest of the three numbers, then choose the other two.